# Is the plane close packed?

Tags: crystal-structure

Is  the (200) plane of fcc crystal structure(the plane parallel to the face of unit cell and passing through the body centre of it) a close packed plane?

A close packed palne is a plane where the neighbouring atoms touch each other.
Eg: (100) of simple cubic
(111)of fcc

But in thiscase when i draw the plane, i got four half circles on the middle edges of the square, touching the atoms on each side. But, they donot touch the atom infront.
So, i have a doubt whether it is close packed?
Please explain.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! This seems like a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.

Comment: Close packing does not mean that the atoms 'touch'. It is just the highest areal density plane in a given crystal structure. And, no, (200) is not it for fcc.